# How to tidy up a JavaScript filter function with many many conditions?

Tags: javascript

Im using React but I think this is just a vanilla JavaScript question. In my data model I have an array of objects. This is a shortened version:

```
this.props.exercises = [
  {
    name: 'Push up',
    equipment: 'none',
    group: 'push'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bench press',
    equipment: 'Barbell',
    group: 'push'
  },
  {
    name: 'Pull-Up Bar',
    equipment: 'Pull-Up Bar',
    group: 'pull'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dumbbell / Kettlebell Squat',
    equipment: ['Dumbbell', 'Kettlebell'],
    group: 'legs'
  }
]
```

I need to do some quite complex filtering on this array. If the item's name matches the chosenExercise string it always needs to be returned. If this condition is not matched then I need the following conditions:

If the user has chosen a group then only exercises from this group should be returned.

If the user has entered search text then the results should also be filtered by this.

The user specifies what equipment they have and then the results should be filtered by this too. Exercises can require no equipment, 1 piece of equipment, or have an array of possible equipment options.

My code below works but I think its quite fragile and will be a nightmare to debug if something goes wrong. What would be a better approach? Can functional programming come to the rescue?

```
renderExercises() {
    const {selectedType} = this.state;
    const allExercises = this.props.exercises;

    // If there is search text then create a var for it
    let searchText = false;
    if (this.searchText && this.searchText.value.length > 0) {
      searchText = this.searchText.value.toLowerCase();
    }

    return (
      allExercises
      // Set the active exercise to have an active property
        .map((item) => {
          if (this.props.chosenExercise === item.name) {
            item.active = true;
          } else {
            item.active = false;
          }
          return item;
        })
        .filter((item) => {
          // If the exercise is active then return true
          if (item.active === true) {
            return true
          }
          // Filter by the exercise group if one is selected
          if (item.group !== selectedType && selectedType !== 'all') {
            return false;
          }
          // If there is search text then filter out non matches
          if (searchText && !item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) {
            return false;
          }

          // EQUIPMENT CONDITIONS
          // If the exercise doesn't need any equipment then return true
          if (item.equipment === 'none') {
            return true;
          }

          // If the user has all equipment then return true
          if (this.props.equipmentSelectionState === 'all') {
            return true;
          }

          // If the item only has 1 piece of equipment then the type will be a string not an array
          if (typeof item.equipment == 'string' || item.equipment instanceof String) {
            // If the selected equipment array contains the items's required equipment then return true
            if (this.props.equipmentSelection.includes(item.equipment)) {
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          } else {
            let test = false;
            item.equipment.forEach((itemEquipment => {
              if (this.props.equipmentSelection.includes(itemEquipment)) {
                test = true;
              }
            }));
            if (test === true) {
              return true;
            }
          }

          return false;
        })
        // Sort by name
        .sort((a, b) => {
          if (a.name < b.name)
            return -1;
          if (a.name > b.name)
            return 1;
          return 0;
        })
        .map((item) => {
          return (
            <ChooseAnExercises
              key={item.name}
              name={item.name}
              active={item.active}
              setNumber={this.props.number}
              updateValue={this.props.updateValue}
            />
          )
        })
    )
  }
```

Comment: I think the question we should be asking is how did you get yourself into this situation. Since all these conditions seem quite important, it's worth it to give it a proper flag in the items and update accordingly when something changes.

Comment: `.map` + `.filter` + `.sort` + `.map` o_0. Sounds too much looping. My suggestion, try to use something like `forEach` or `reduce` and cut down iterations. There is also a `.foraEach` which I missed

Comment: One basic pointer, whenever you have code like `if(condition) return true; else return false;`, this is just unnecessary. Just do `return condition` or `return !!condition`

Comment: you could omit checks for `true` or false, just return the value. the last equipment collection could be replaced by a `some` method.

Comment: you're doing too much basically, the theme of everyones comments is to do less and restructure your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shrink the filter part by using only `true` conditions and sort them by taking general conditions first and then come to the more kind of expensive operations, like iterating arrays.

```
.filter(item =>
    item.active ||
    item.equipment === 'none' ||
    this.props.equipmentSelectionState === 'all' ||
    selectedType === 'all' ||
    item.group === selectedType ||
    searchText && item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
    (Array.isArray(item.equipment)
        ? item.equipment
        : [item.equipment]
    ).some(itemEquipment => this.props.equipmentSelection.includes(itemEquipment))
)
```

All of the condions are chained with logical OR. If necessary, a string is converted to an array for iterating with the same check.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to filter multiple times. Try this simple approach.

**Demo below**

```js
var exercises = [{
    name: 'Push up',
    equipment: 'none',
    group: 'push'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bench press',
    equipment: 'Barbell',
    group: 'push'
  },
  {
    name: 'Pull-Up Bar',
    equipment: 'Pull-Up Bar',
    group: 'pull'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dumbbell / Kettlebell Squat',
    equipment: ['Dumbbell', 'Kettlebell'],
    group: 'legs'
  }
];
var searchName = "Push up";
var searchGroup = "push";
var searchText = "Dumbbell";

//as per priority do the name search first.
var directSeachNameMatches = exercises.filter((s) => s.name == searchName);
//Do a group search if direct name search doesn't give anything back
var groupMatches = directSeachNameMatches.length ? directSeachNameMatches : exercises.filter((s) => s.group == searchGroup);
//Do a text search if group name search doesn't give anything back
var searchTextMatches = groupMatches.length ? groupMatches : exercises.filter(function(s) {
  if (!Array.isArray(s.equipment)) {
    s.equipment = [s.equipment]
  };
  return s.equipment.indexOf(searchText) != -1;
});
var finalMatch = searchTextMatches ;

console.log(finalMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with some basic simplifications:

- `if (x === true)` should be `if (x)` (unless your variable can hold values of different types, which it really should not in the first place)
- `if (x) return true; else return false` should be `return x`
- `test = false; x.forEach(v => { if (p(v)) test = true; })` should be `test = x.some(p)`

Then, change your data. As already said, you shouldn't have different types of values in the same place, specifically don't have `equipment` either be a `string`, a `String` instance, or an `Array`. Just make it always an array of strings!

- Instead of the value `'none'`, have an empty array
- Instead of a string, have a singleton array with that string as its element

Now we can at least simplify to

```
return (
  allExercises
  // Set the active exercise to have an active property
    .map((item) => {
      item.active = (this.props.chosenExercise === item.name);
      return item;
    })
    .filter((item) => {
      // If the exercise is active then return true
      if (item.active) {
        return true
      }
      // Filter by the exercise group if one is selected
      if (item.group !== selectedType && selectedType !== 'all') {
        return false;
      }
      // If there is search text then filter out non matches
      if (searchText && !item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) {
        return false;
      }

      // If the exercise doesn't need any equipment then return true
      if (!item.equipment.length) {
        return true;
      }
      // If the user has all equipment then return true
      if (this.props.equipmentSelectionState === 'all') {
        return true;
      }
      return item.equipment.some(itemEquipment =>
        this.props.equipmentSelection.includes(itemEquipment)
      );
    })
```

Now transform this into a single boolean expression:

```
    .filter(item =>
      item.active// If the exercise is active then return true
      || (item.group === selectedType || selectedType == 'all') // Filter by the exercise group if one is selected
      && (!searchText || item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) // If there is search text then filter out non matches
      && (this.props.equipmentSelectionState === 'all' // If the user has all equipment then return true
        || !item.equipment.length // If the exercise doesn't need any equipment then return true
        || item.equipment.some(itemEquipment =>
          this.props.equipmentSelection.includes(itemEquipment)
        )
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that trying to not filter the active item was preventing me from chaining filters, which I think is the easiest and more readable solution. So instead I remove the active item and store it in a separate object and add it back after I'm done filtering.

```
return (
      allExercises
      // Set the active exercise to have an active property
        .filter((item) => {
          if (this.props.chosenExercise === item.name) {
            item.active = true;
            Object.assign(activeItem, item);
            return false; // Remove the active element so we can add it later independent of filtering
          } else {
            item.active = false;
            return true;
          }
        })
        .filter(item => {
          const {selectedType} = this.state;
          if (selectedType === 'all') return true; // If 'all' exercise group is selected then let everything pass
          if (item.group === selectedType) return true; // If the selected exercise group matches the exercise's group then pass
        })
        .filter(item => {
          if (!searchText) {
            return true; // If no search text let everything pass
          } else if (item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) {
            return true; // If there is search text then match against this
          }
        })
        .filter(item => {
          if (item.equipment === 'none') return true; // If exercise doesn't need equipment then always pass
          if (this.props.equipmentSelectionState === 'all') return true; // If user has all equipment selected then always pass
          // item.equipment is a string if there is only 1 piece of equipment required by the exercise
          if (typeof item.equipment === 'string') {
            // Check the users selected equipment for a match
            if (this.props.equipmentSelection.includes(item.equipment)) {
              return true;
            }
          } else {
            // item.equipment is an array
            let test = false;
            this.props.equipmentSelection.forEach((equipmentSelection) => {
              item.equipment.forEach(itemEquipment => {
                if (itemEquipment === equipmentSelection) {
                  test = true;
                }
              });
            });
            return test;
          }
        })
        // Sort by name
        .concat(activeItem) // Add the active item we removed earlier
        .filter((item) => {
          // Filter out the empty result which is pushed when no exercise is active
          if (Object.keys(item).length > 0) return true;
        })
        .sort((a, b) => {
          // Sort alphabetically
          if (a.name < b.name)
            return -1;
          if (a.name > b.name)
            return 1;
          return 0;
        })
        .map((item) => {
          return (
            <ChooseAnExercises
              key={item.name}
              name={item.name}
              active={item.active}
              setNumber={this.props.number}
              updateValue={this.props.updateValue}
            />
          )
        })
    )
```